# Voting is borked in triage review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, triage

The vote buttons (those grey triangles in the screenshot) don't do anything in the triage review queue.

[image: screenshot]

They also only appear when you've already reviewed the item and gone back, which seems strange.

Comment: @Deduplicator This report (although it could be a bit clearer... a screenshot would help *hint hint*) is talking about voting *arrows* on a previously reviewed item.

Comment: Well, now it's obviously another issue. Should get fixed soon then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this is in the process of building out.  Thanks for the report!