# "Vote up" button does not work as it should in Triage

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, triage

In the new Triage review queue, when looking at certain existing review items, there exists a "Vote up" button in the top right corner that allows me to upvote a post without clicking on the up arrow.

The way it's programmed on each page load is like this:

1. Detect the current upvote state, and enable itself if not upvoted.
2. If clicked, disable itself and remain disabled always. Otherwise, always remain enabled if enabled in the first place.
3. Once clicked, act as though I clicked the vote arrow myself (upvote if not already and retract if already voted).

However, there are a couple of quirks with it:

1. Clicking the "Vote Up" button and then retracting the vote by clicking the actual arrow should re-enable the button, not leave it permanently disabled until the page is refreshed.
2. Clicking the actual vote arrow on the post should also automatically disable the button. Clicking the "Vote Up" button retracts the vote if I've already upvoted it, either using the actual arrow in the review or outside of the review item before accessing the review item.

In other words, the "Vote Up" button needs to remain exactly in sync with the actual vote, enabling itself when I haven't upvoted yet disabling when I have. It needs to go hand in hand with the actual vote arrow. Making it the way it is now will produce the aforementioned bugs.

Comment: Maybe related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278407/voting-is-borked-in-triage-review-queue

Comment: @Deduplicator Nope; completely unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have decided to go with a slightly different UI for the Vote up button.  Basically we removed it so this should no longer be an issue.

Comment: Yep, I no longer see the button, and I instead see the entire vote mechanism shake a few times. Perhaps you should emphasize the up arrow a little more?